# Could somebody explain alpha channeling in tokamaks?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, nuclear-physics, plasma-physics

Could somebody explain alpha channeling in Tokamaks and mirror machines? Energetic alpha particles (in the center of the torus or mirror device) born in fusion reactions, interact with a wave and transfer some of its energy to it. But, what kind of wave? Ion acoustic waves or radio waves? And then, this wave is supposed to heat the fuel nuclei. Now ,the alpha particles are supposed to diffuse out the the periphery. How can that happen?

Comment: It is an electron plasma wave. The energy transfer mechanism is known as landau damping.

Comment: If you google "Alpha Channeling in Mirror Machines and in Tokamaks" an article comes up in https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228625288_Alpha_Channeling_in_Mirror_Machines_and_in_Tokamaks where you can download the pdf that has the explanations.

Comment: @hsinghal - Are you saying Langmuir waves are heating alpha-particles?

Comment: @honeste_vivere no I am saying another way around. alpha particles give energy to electron plasma wave. Yes, the electron plasma wave can also transfer energy to particles too, which is the principle behind hot electron generation. But in this case there is a large population of energetic alpha particles hence energy goes from alpha particles to the electron wave.

Comment: @hsinghal - Okay, what do you mean by "electron plasma wave"?  Are you referring to a Langmuir-like oscillation?  If so, just how energetic are these alpha-particles because it usually takes a bump-on-tail electron instability (i.e., fast electrons moving well above the electron thermal speed) to drive Langmuir-like oscillations unstable.